# Dynamic LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, dynamic-linq

I am trying to use [Dynamic LINQ Expressions](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions) with [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview), but having troubles with dynamic parameters.

Here's an example query from Dynamic LINQ Wiki:

```
var query = db.Customers
    .Where("City == @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10)
    .OrderBy("CompanyName")
    .Select("new(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

In my case for example I am trying to query the following structure:

```
<DataCenter>
   <Server IP="1.2.3.4">
       <OS>Windows</OS>
   </Server>
   <Server IP="5.6.7.8">
       <OS>Linux</OS>
   </Server>
</DataCenter>
```

I am trying to read and parse it like this:

```
XElement XmlSource = XElement.Load(filePath)
var query = XmlSource.Elements().AsQueryable().Select("???????");
```

What do I put as a string parameter? For example if I try to retrieve IP and OS of all servers. When I try to use `Element( )` or `Attribute( )` methods of XElement I get error that "*XElement doesn't have such property or method*".

Though `firstAtteibute` and `firstNode` seems available. And something like this works:

```
var query = XmlSource.Elements()
         .AsQueryable()
         .Select("new (FirstAttribute.Value as IP, FirstNode.toString() as OS)");
```

Comment: Gee thanks for the downvote and close vote. How nice of you.

Comment: what are you trying to access? theres no need for `AsQueryable` here.

Comment: @DanielA.White Dynamic LINQ expressions built on top of IQueryable as far as I understand. I am trying to run queries on arbitrary fields supplied by user. I've added example from Dynamic LINQ Wiki.

Comment: @DanielA.White Answer below by NetMage is exactly what I was asking. Sorry about being unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`, you can add `XName` and `XElement` to the *accessible types* so they will work:

```
public class MyCustomTypeProvider : DefaultDynamicLinqCustomTypeProvider {
    public override HashSet<Type> GetCustomTypes() => new[] { typeof(XName), typeof(XElement) }.ToHashSet();
}
```

Since Dynamic LINQ doesn't use implicit conversions for method lookup, and doesn't understand explicit conversions, I showed two different ways to handle conversion of `string` to `XName` normally done by implicit conversion:

```
ParsingConfig.Default.CustomTypeProvider = new MyCustomTypeProvider();

var OSName = (XName)"OS";
var query = XmlSource.Elements().AsQueryable()
                .Select("new (Attribute(XName.Get(\"IP\")).Value as IP, Element(@0).Value as OS)", OSName);
```

If it is possible for the element `OS` to be missing, you must test for `null`. Unfortunately, I have not been able to get the `np` predicate to work:

```
var query = XmlSource.Elements().AsQueryable()
                .Select("new (Attribute(XName.Get(\"IP\")).Value as IP, (Element(@0) != null ? Element(@0).Value : null) as OS)", OSName);
```

Comment: You're a genius! This works like a charm. I have 2 questions though: One: why we're passing name differently to Attribute and Element? Or it doesn't make a difference where we convert String to XName? And second - if the attribute doesn't exist I am getting NullReferenceException. What would be the best place to add safeguards checking for null? Thanks!

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I passed them differently to just show possible ways to solve the lack of implicit or explicit conversion support in Dynamic LINQ. Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I extended my answer for missing element.

Comment: hopefully you can help me with another issue. I can successfully run dynamic LINQ query, but when I try to export results to CSV using this method (https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsKeepItSimpleAndDevelopYourSenseOfSmellFromLinqToCSV.aspx) it is passed as IEnumerable of type "Object" for witch GetProperties() returns nothing. Is there a way to enumerate properties of Item returned by Dynamic LINQ?

Comment: NM, I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To Retrieve Attribute and descendent Element You can try below code:

```
string StringXML = @"<DataCenter>
                       <Server IP='1.2.3.4'>
                           <OS>Windows</OS>
                       </Server>
                       <Server IP='5.6.7.8'>
                           <OS>Linux</OS>
                       </Server>
                    </DataCenter>";


XDocument Doc = XDocument.Parse(StringXML);

var nodess = from Servers in Doc.Descendants("Server")
                select new{IP = Servers.Attribute("IP").Value , OS=Servers.Element("OS").Value} ;

foreach(var node in nodess)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ServerIP:"+node.IP + " ServerOS:" +node.OS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but `select` needs to be dynamic, I don't know in advance which elements/attributes will be requested

Answer (score 0):

```
    string xml =
            "<DataCenter><Server IP=\"1.2.3.4\"><OS>Windows</OS></Server><Server IP=\"5.6.7.8\"><OS>Linux</OS></Server></DataCenter>";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var servers = doc.Elements("DataCenter").Elements("Server");

    var results = from s in doc.Elements("DataCenter").Elements("Server") where (string)s.Attribute("IP") == "1.2.3.4" select s;
```

EDIT:

Since it's XML and we want the values from the elements/attributes why not just grab their `Value` property. Then there is no reason to deal with the accessible types.

```
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var results = from s in doc2.Descendants("Server") select new { OsName = s.Element("OS").Value, IpAddress = s.Attribute("IP").Value };
```

Comment: I am using dynamic LINQ, I don't know in advance what the condition or requested fields will be. If you take a look at the example at the bottom of my post - parameters are strings that can be constructed

Comment: I've edited to my post. Since it's XML and we want the values from the elements/attributes why not just grab the Value.